# About the role of total variation measure on boundary reflected stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

I am reading [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hmj/1206135203) about stochastic differential equations with reflecting boundary conditions. In page 165, an example equation with an explicit solution is presented. However, I can't see that condition 2.3 in the same page, namely:

> The set $\\{ t\in \mathbb{R}^+ : \xi(t)\in D\\}$ has $\mathrm{d}|\varphi|$-measure zero.

holds for every instance of such example. Taking $\xi$ to be any continuous path such that $\xi[0,t_0] \subseteq \partial D$, $\xi(t_0, +\infty) \subseteq D$, the total variation $|\varphi|$ would be constant and positive in $[t_0, +\infty)$, so

$$ \int_{t_0}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}|\varphi|(s) =  \int_{t_0}^{+\infty} |\varphi|(s) \mathrm{d}s > 0$$

and this would be a counterexample. What am I reading incorrectly?